# Wrapper for the matlab to read sparse data file

Tags: matlab, sorting, text, awk, libsvm

Libsvm can read the following datafile and convert it into sparse data structure in matlab (using libsvmread).

```
-1 3:1 11:1 14:1 19:1 39:1 42:1 55:1 64:1 67:1 73:1 75:1 76:1 80:1 83:1 
-1 3:1 6:1 17:1 27:1 35:1 40:1 57:1 63:1 69:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 81:1 103:1
```

First column is a label for the binary classification and other columns are feature vectors. For example in first column only positions 3,11,14,19... are non zero.

I have a file in which these positions are not sorted. For example it could be like -

```
-1 11:1 3:1 14:1 19:1 39:1 42:1 55:1 64:1 67:1 73:1 75:1 76:1 80:1 83:1
```

Libsvmread won't work in such a situation. Is there anyway, where I can sort the data (according to positions) or is there any exisiting code which can help me extract this data in matlab?

The goal is that given this sample Input

```
-1 11:1 3:1 14:1 19:1 39:1 42:1 55:1 64:1 67:1 73:1 75:1 76:1 80:1 83:1 
-1 3:1 2:1 6:1 4:1 17:1 27:1 35:1 40:1 57:1 63:1 69:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 81:1 103:1
```

We get the following output:

```
-1 3:1 11:1 14:1 19:1 39:1 42:1 55:1 64:1 67:1 73:1 75:1 76:1 80:1 83:1
-1 2:1 3:1 4:1 6:1 17:1 27:1 35:1 40:1 57:1 63:1 69:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 81:1 103:1
```

Comment: from this 
-1 11:1 3:1 14:1 19:1 39:1 42:1 55:1 64:1 67:1 73:1 75:1 76:1 80:1 83:1 

to

-1 3:1 11:1 14:1 19:1 39:1 42:1 55:1 64:1 67:1 73:1 75:1 76:1 80:1 83:1

Comment: edit your question with this info, do not add it in commetns

Comment: I was trying using awk (not that familiar with it). I noted all columns in the text file and stored them separately and then was trying to sort them somehow. 
Other thing is to change the libsvm code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all the info in an array `a[]` and then sort using indices:

```
awk '{delete a
      for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) 
          a[$i+0]=$i
      n=asorti(a, sorted, "@ind_num_asc")
      printf "%s%s", $1, OFS
      for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
          printf "%s%s", a[sorted[i]], (i==n?ORS:OFS)}' file
```

#### Explanation

This uses [asorti()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html) and [`@ind_num_asc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning) to define the ordering mode.

For every line, we store in an array `a[]` all the data starting on the 2nd field. Then, we sort it numerically and print it back, in the sorted order.

- `delete a` remove the array, so that we just append data from this line.
- `for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) a[$i+0]=$i` store each field as an element in the array. By saying `$i+0` we convert `xx:yy` into just `xx`, so that the indices will just be the left part of the field.
- `n=asorti(a, sorted, "@ind_num_asc")` sort the array using its indices and store it in `sorted[]` array. By saying `@ind_num_asc` we tell `asorti` to use indices, numerically and ascendent order.
- `printf "%s%s", $1, OFS` print the first field, the one that is alone.
- `for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", a[sorted[i]], (i==n?ORS:OFS)` loop through the sorted values and print them.

#### Test

```
$ awk '{delete a; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {a[$i+0]=$i}; n=asorti(a, sorted, "@ind_num_asc"); printf "%s%s", $1, OFS; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", a[sorted[i]], (i==n?ORS:OFS)}' a
1 3:1 11:1 14:1 19:1 39:1 42:1 55:1 64:1 67:1 73:1 75:1 76:1 80:1 83:1
-1 2:1 3:1 4:1 6:1 17:1 27:1 35:1 40:1 57:1 63:1 69:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 81:1 103:1
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks a lot for the quick answer. But this works when there is a single line in the text. When there are multiple lines, code gives very different answer.

Comment: from your question I understood data is just on one line. So you have multiple lines and you have to sort each one of them? Please provide then a more relevant set of data

Comment: @user3727929 see update. I did refactor completely. Check if it works, then I can update with some explanations

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking a dumb question, but how do I store content of a file into an array? 
and is asorti predefined function in the awk?

Comment: `asorti()` is in GNU awks. You can check if this is your case by saying `awk --version`. Also, you don't have to worry about the insights, because `awk` handles all of this. Just store the data in a file with the format you mentioned in the question and run this code.

Comment: @user3727929 you are welcome, I did some research in the solution so I also learnt a lot from it! Just updated with some explanations

Answer (score 0):

Although I like the awk answer, there is another one which will work for your setup.

```
while read line; do echo $line | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n | tr '\n' ' '; echo ""; done < inputfile
```

That is transpose the row into a column and use sort, then transpose again; based on the format given first element will be sorted numerically upfront.